# MySQL SELECT WHERE Multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table like this
[image]

Creating google charts, so i need couple of DB queries to create JSON. Everything is done but having hard time with DB query.

1. Solved this query.
2. Need to select all billable and all nonbillable hours, sum of them grouped by date. So to get for each day sum of billable and non-billable hours.

Currently i have single query,

```
$json = array();
$sql = "SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`hours`)) as seconds,date FROM `am_am2_time_tracking` WHERE is_billable = 1 GROUP BY date";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{   
    $bil_hours = floatval($row['seconds'] / 60 / 60);
    $json[] = array('date'=>$row['date'],'bill_hours'=>$bil_hours);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

which gives me this json:

```
[{"date":"2016-02-03","bill_hours":12.5},{"date":"2016-02-04","bill_hours":6},{"date":"2016-02-12","bill_hours":3},{"date":"2016-02-13","bill_hours":4},{"date":"2016-02-18","bill_hours":1.25},{"date":"2016-02-19","bill_hours":1},{"date":"2016-02-26","bill_hours":1.75},{"date":"2016-02-27","bill_hours":0.5}]
```

But instead of creating new query, looking for better way to have both hours in single json.

Comment: 1. Managed to solve first one with

$sql = "SELECT is_billable,hours, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`hours`)) as `Count` FROM `am_am2_time_tracking` GROUP BY `is_billable`";

but not sure about number 2.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try make the following query

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`hours`)) as seconds,date FROM `am_am2_time_tracking` GROUP BY date, is_billable";
```